# random lat lng coordinates within x km's of another lat lng

Tags: geometry, geo

We have a location specified by a lat & lng

We want to generate some other random lat & lng locations within say 20km of this location

Does anyone have a good formula for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate two uniform random values `r` and `Fi` in range `0..1`
Calculate distance as `d = Radius * Sqrt(r)` ([description here for plane circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html))
Calculate bearing as `Theta=2 * Pi * Fi`
Find lat/lon coordinates for given central point and calculated d and Theta as [described here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) in section `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point`

```
JavaScript:
(all angles 
in radians)
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(θ) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(θ)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, 
θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), d being the distance travelled, 
R the earth’s radius
```